# Database design for recurring calendar events with infinities

Tags: database-design, calendar, recurring-events

From a database perspective, what is the best implementation/design considering the following:

1. Recurring calendar events that are infinite (no end date)? Obviously, it does not make sense to populate database records for each and every event!
2. After recurring events are created, what is the best approach to editing a single event that breaks the recurring rule? For example, "Every Monday at 9:00 AM" but there is one particular Monday that needs to start at 10:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to suggest changes to a schema with absolutely no details, but here is one way. What you have is an entry that says "from this date forward, the meeting time is on this day at this time."

```
EffDate    DOW   Time
01/01/2017 Mon   0900
03/14/2017 Mon   1000
03/21/2017 Mon   0900
```

Starting on the first day of the schedule, Jan 1, the meeting is held on Monday at 9am. Then, starting on the Tuesday before it takes effect, the meeting the next Monday (on the 20th) will be at 10am. Starting again on the 21st, the meeting time reverts to 9am.

The query to make this work looks a little complicated, but follow the logic and it should be obvious.

```
select  Dow "Day of meeting", Time
from    MeetingSchedule ms
where   ms.EffDate =(
        select  Max( ms1.EffDate )
        from    MeetingSchedule ms1
        where   ms1.EffDate <= Today()
        );
```

If this query is executed any time on or after Jan 1 to just before Mar 14 (which is a Tuesday), the return will show Monday at 9am. Starting the next day and for an entire week, the return will show Monday at 10am. Then Starting the next day (and from then on), the time will once again show 9am.

Of course, you might want to know what the meeting time will be on any given Monday. The date will go into a variable which will replace the function returning the execution date.

```
select  :DateOfInterest "Week starting", Dow "Day of meeting", Time
from    MeetingSchedule ms
where   ms.EffDate =(
        select  Max( ms1.EffDate )
        from    MeetingSchedule ms1
        where   ms1.EffDate <= :DateOfInterest
        );
```

Assuming you go through a loop generating the dates of consecutive Sundays, the output would look like this for the month of March:

```
Week starting   Day of meeting Time
   03/05/2017   Mon            0900
   03/12/2017   Mon            0900
   03/19/2017   Mon            1000
   03/26/2017   Mon            0900
```

But the correct answer will be given for any date after the last meeting before the change to the date of the meeting itself. If the time were to change to 10am from then on, simply eliminate the last row, which reverts it back to 9am.

I added Day of Week but you can leave that out if you know that the meeting will absolutely, always be on a Monday.